# Find $f^{(k)}(0)$ of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm stuck with this problem:

> If $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$, find $f^{(k)}(0)$. Hint: Find the power series of f.

I tried to solve it by writing down the Taylor series of $$\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}-...$$

After that I divided the whole series by $x$: $$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=f(x)$$. The problem is that when I plug in $0$ in $f(x)$, I get $f(0)=$undefined. Also, When I differentiate and plug in $0$ I always get $0$, what am I doing wrong? How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: If you plug in $0$ in $f(x)$ you get $f(0)=1$.  This is given in the question.

Comment: Ok, so $f(0)=0$, but If I differentiate, I will always end up with $0$, because there will always be that $x$ on the numerator, right?

Comment: Write the RHS as an explicit expression without using summation notation and I think you will see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I would be $\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{9!}-...$, right? So when $n=0$, $f(0)=1$.

Comment: The first derivative would be $-\frac{2x}{ 3!} + ...$ thus $f'(0)=0$. The sond derivative would be $-\frac{2}{3!}+...$, thus $f''(0)=-\frac{1}{3}$, right? I see now, So it would be a number when $n$ is even and $0$ when $n$ is odd?

Comment: Zero is a number!!!  So it is always a number, non-zero when $n$ is even.

Comment: And the point is that in the summation, if $x$ is zero, then $x^n$ does **not** give you zero when $n=0$.

Comment: @David I know zero is a number, I expressed myself poorly. I meant that it would be some number, like you said non-zero.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just one more question. How would the kth derivative look when n is even? Because I think I had it wrong.

Comment: Use the second formula in the answer from Minus One-Twelfth.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you know that $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k},$$ then $$a_{k} = \dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}.$$

(Try and show this!)

Also remember that if you are plugging in $x = 0$ to a term of a power series where the power of $x$ is $0$, the term should be $1$, not $0$ (i.e. substituting $x = 0$ into something like $x^{k}$ when $k = 0$ should be treated as $1$, not $0$).

For example, if $g(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}x^{k}$, then if you substitute $x = 0$, what do you get?

Comment: Isn't that the Taylor series? In don't understand why $x^k$ when $x=0$ and $k=0$ is $1$. Isn't $0^0$ undefined?

Comment: The $k = 0$ term is just a constant term essentially. For example, if $g(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2}a_{k}x^{k}$, this means $g(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2}$, so substituting $x = 0$ gives us $a_{0}$, so has the effect of giving $0$ in all the terms except in the $a_{0}$ term.

Comment: I see,so I just had to think that way. Thanks!